# S3 lifecycle rule with suffix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bunch of files in an S3 bucket. I'd like to create a rule to delete all of the files that end in .pdf after 1 day.

Can I do this with S3 lifecycle rules?

Because I tried `*.pdf delete after 1 day`, and that didn't work.

I also tried something like `copy_* delete after 1 day` and that didn't work either.

Comment: Solution to the similar question can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76773741/2732729

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to the question. As you noticed, suffix-based rules aren't supported.
However, you can use tags. You do need to tag your objects as you upload them, and you can do that regardless of your upload method (CLI or console).
You can enable tagging for existing objects, as well. Again, either through console or CLI (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-tagging.html).

Once tagging is done, make a lifecycle rule that's only applicable to objects associated with that tag.

Tags are replicated (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-what-is-isnot-replicated.html). So if you have replication enabled, this setup works in destination, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to do this. Since lifecycle rules still don't support suffix-based rules, I wrote a quick and dirty python script that would tag all files for me. This script can even tag across buckets, based on any suffix specified.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3

# Setup session. I use SSO so this may be slightly different for you if you don't.
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='your-profile-name')

# Connection to S3 Client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# If tagging a single bucket use this 
bucket = 'your-bucket'

# Get all object keys. We need to specify keys in all later steps
response = s3.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket= bucket,
    Delimiter="\n"
)

# We are only interested in the metadata about the contents
response = response['Contents']
keys = [] # List of keys globally accessible

file_suffix = 'pdf'

for key in response:
    if key.get('Key').endswith(file_suffix):
        keys.append(key.get('Key'))
    else:
        print('no pdf files found')
        exit()
    

for key in keys:
    obj = s3.put_object_tagging(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=key,
        Tagging={
        'TagSet': [
            {
                'Key': 'file_type',
                'Value': file_suffix
            }
        ]
        }
    )
```

There may be a more efficient delimiter see https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/list_objects_v2.html

Answer (score -2):

Why don't run a shall script on you ec2 with a cronjob which deletes the .pdf files.

Comment: That would be a solution, but it doesn't answer the question "Can you do this with S3 lifecycle rules?"

Comment: i dont want to run a shall script because it means i need to start a machine to run it .. but two years on it still does not seem you can have a lifecycle rule based on suffix http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html

Comment: Having a script iterate through thousands of objects in s3 sounds like a bad idea...