# Lifecycle rule for files in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, lifecycle

I have a combination of .pdf and .jpg files in S3 bucket. Is it possible to add lifecycle to only (.pdf files) ?

All the examples i see points me to setting lifecycle rule for the whole bucket or a specific folder inside a bucket. But i am not able to find any examples showing how to set for a specific file extension inside a bucket.

I am using the following terraform code

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "<<bucket_name>>"
  acl    = "private"

  lifecycle_rule {
    id      = "log"
    enabled = true
    prefix  = "path/"

    expiration {
      days = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html#intro-lifecycle-rules-filter - does not look like suffix matching is possible, you can try adding the file type as a tag to each file and then using tags for filtering

Comment: Can you storage the .pdf files in a diferente path that .jpg files? You can filter by path without any problem.

Comment: Luckily I have only pdf(s) inside specific bucket. So i am specifying the root folder and it works just fine. but it needs serious planning for future segregation

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar ask in my case. The way we segregated pdf files is by tagging them and applying lifecycle to the bucket using tag filter.

I have authored a lambda which does the tagging of pdf files and trigger has been set using EventBridge that runs this lambda once a day. Please find below the lambda code in Python.

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    my_bucket=s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
    for my_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
        if my_object.key.endswith("pdf"):
            response=client.put_object_tagging(
                Bucket='my-bucket',
                Key=my_object.key,
                Tagging={
                    'TagSet': 
                        [
                            {
                                'Key': 'DeleteFlag',
                                'Value': 'True'
                            }
                        ]
                }
            )
    return {
        "statusCode": 200
    }
```

If you run this lambda, all the pdf files will be tagged with Key as DeleteFlag and Value as True. The same Object tag needs to be used as filter to the bucket lifecycle policy.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add lifecycle to only (.pdf files) ?

Sadly its not. The lifecycles work only on prefix, not suffix. One way is to separate them to different prefixes or even buckets, e.g.

- path/jpgs/
- path/pdfs/

I think separation would be more beneficial in the long term for other use-cases.